# multiple linear regression for bounded variable

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, beta-regression

I am aware that there are special models that deal with bounded variables (binomial, logistic, beta regression) and all have different benefits and are used for different data types.

However, I read on the [SAS website](http://support.sas.com/kb/57/480.html) that if most of my bounded data are within the range between 0.3 - 0.7, classical multiple linear regression can be applied.

> Proportion data typically exhibit a sigmoidal, or S-shaped, curve with
>   asymptotes at the limits of zero and one when plotted against a
>   predictor. In general, ordinary regression does not capture this
>   relationship, but it might be reasonable if all of the data fall in
>   the middle of the range (between about 0.3 and 0.7) where the curve is
>   approximately linear. However, there are other approaches that can be
>   used.

I found this argument on numerous websites, but cannot find it in any literature: [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/proportions-as-dependent-variable-in-regression-which-type-of-model/), [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_use_multiple_linear_regression_when_the_dependant_variable_is_a_percentage_with_a_range_from_zero_to_hundred)

**Any literature that supports this argument?**